# js prevent selection wrap if it contains element

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which wraps selected text in a span:

```
if (window.getSelection) {
                text = window.getSelection();
                if (text.rangeCount) {
                    if(text==""||text.toString().trim() == ""||text.anchorNode.parentNode.nodeName=="SPAN"){return false;}
                    var range = text.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
                    range.surroundContents(span);
                    text.addRange(range);
                    text.removeAllRanges();
                }
            }
```

using the following argument I successfully prevented wrapping the same selection twice:

```
if(text.anchorNode.parentNode.nodeName=="SPAN"){return false;}
```

But if I select a larger portion of text around the span it still wraps it. Is there a way I can check weather my selection contains a span element inside it and return false based on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is `span` being create, before the line `range.surroundContents(span)` ?

This fixes it for me:

```
var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
range.surroundContents(newSpan);
```

Here's a screenshot of the DOM after adding the above lines, then selecting some text as described:

[image]

**EDIT** Here is the updated code as per clarification in comments.

```
  /**
   * This line will check if the selected text is already inside a <span>
   * ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   * text.anchorNode.parentNode.nodeName === 'SPAN'
   *
   * This line will check if the selected text contains a <span> within it
   * ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   * text.anchorNode.parentNode.querySelector('span') !== null
   * 
   */

  if( text === '' || text.toString().trim() === '' || text.anchorNode.parentNode.querySelector('span') !== null) { 
    console.log('<span> inside selection - returning'); 
    return false; 
  }
```

Comment: It was before the if(window.getSelection()), I tried relocating it just before the range.surroundContents(newSpan); but it gives the same result, just as you showed in the image this is what Im trying to avoid

Comment: My apologies - I thought that was the desired effect. Let me see.

Comment: that prevents me from creating any other spans in that spans parent while I only need to prevent spans which wrap that same span

Comment: Then you're going to need more cases... keep checking if the parentNode contains a span, only if then if it's in a span. This solves one level of it though, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String.indexOf() function to determine if there is a span element in your text.

```
if( text.indexOf("<span") > -1 ){return false;}
```